# application trying to use net.exe to map shared folder on different domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, network-share, windows-service, cross-domain

I am a c# developer running in to issues with a program of mine that tries to transfer files on to a shared folder on a computer which is on a different domain. i.e my windows service sits on domain 'X' and the shared folder is on domain 'Y'. I am trying to map the folder on to Domain 'X' in my program using the "net use" command. and I am getting a "network not found" error. I am guessing this is because the shared folder is on domain "Y" and domain X has issues while trying to connect to a computer on domain Y.
The net.exe command works perfectly with shared folders inside of domain X.
Is there a way i can work through this issue. My only option is to map a drive on to my hosting computer programatically.
I would highly appreciate any help on this issue since i am out of ideas :(

Thanks
Karry

UPDATE: Got it working. I had to remove an extra backslash from the end of the shared folder name in order to get it to work from my c# service. That backslash ate up my day...Sorry guys. it turns out to be embarassing for me now.

Comment: Windows services are not allowed to map drives.

Comment: @mailq: That's not strictly true but, in general, I'd highly discourage any architecture for a service that involves "mapped" "drives".

Comment: Thanks All..for the help and suggestions. It turned out that the shared folder name was the cause of getting the "network not found" error. I had to remove a "\" from the end of it to get it to work from my c# program.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information on what errors you are getting?
Most probably if it's not a connectivity issue (ping,logon to the other domain)
it might be a security issue where programmatically you would have to impersonate 
another user or make sure that the user that executes your program has sufficient priviledges

P.S. since I don't have enough rep to add a comment; [mailq why windows services are not allowed to map network drives?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385418.aspx)